# QuerySet appends _id in a field django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a model below

```
class HomeImages (models.Model):

    homepage_id=models.ForeignKey(HomeAbout,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    home_image=models.ImageField(upload_to="home_image",blank=True,null=True)
```

I using a filter for a serializer

```
  def get(self,request,homeid):

        try:
            homeimg = HomeImages.objects.filter(homepage_id=homeid).values()
        except (KeyError, HomeImages.DoesNotExist):
            return Response('Data not found', status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            if len(homeimg)>0:
                print("home object",homeimg)
                return Response([HomeImgSerializer(dat).data for dat in homeimg])
            return Response([],status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

problem is when I got the result of filter in homeimg object, it returns 
the field of homepage_id as homepage_id_id which incorrect how can I fix this it should mentioned homepage_id in result of queryset?
Below is the queryset result

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'homepage_id_id': 1, 'home_image': 'home_image/edit.png'}]>
```

it shows homepage_id_id, whereas in model it is defined as homepage_id

Comment: Defining your field **`homepage`** instead of `homepage_id` will solve the issue.

Comment: if I define homepage, it saves as homepage_id, if i save as homepage_id it saves as homepage_id_id

Comment: that's how Django is designed to be

Comment: When I try to pass it to the serializer it gives me error it needs homepage, but the django passing is homepage_id. Its the first time i am facing this type of issue it think there may be some other problem due to which it is giving error